# Possible IE XSS Attack found for uploading svg in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, svg, xss, image-uploading, joomla3.0

I tried to upload SVG file in joomla 3 with default media manager,
so i found this solutions:

```
add .svg extension in Configuration -> media manager -> legal extensions

add image/svg+xml mime type in Configuration -> media manager -> legal mime-type
```

I even disabled check mime type and check file type in this area

now when i want to upload svg file i got this error:

```
Possible IE XSS Attack found
```

what shall i do?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't do it with default media manager. This is an XSS Attack risk so by default svg files will be rejected. You can try to do it with another file explorer like [FILEman](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/file-management/fileman) or [eXtplorer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/file-management/extplorer).